# perforce streams and child branches with same pom versions

Tags: stream, branch, perforce

i'm looking for best practice for working with Perforce .
my scenario is:
i have Main branch that contains many modules with specific pom version.
now i want to create with P4 child branches that will take the code from the main and after that i will be able to do Merge Down-Copy up.
my issue is that i must change the pom versions in the child branch in case i want to run it on some CI since i dont want to override the artifacts of Main branch.

is there some best practice for that?
i have WA to run script that will change pom versions in the child branch but i believe that there is some mechanism that solving this issue but didn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you kept the 'pom' files in a separate stream, you could use 'import' to import the versions you need in to specific streams.

It is possible to import files at a specific changelist version.

More information about the 'import' functionality is available here:
  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.streams.html

Comment: tnx for your answer , the import will not help since i new pom version or other option to avoid the override of the artifacts from main in the new stream, i want to have CI for any child branch but not to do update the pom versions manually